# Verify Divergence Theorem for $F(x,y,z)=(xz,0,0)$ on a solid bounded by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

Here is the problem: "Verify Gauss Theorem for $F:\mathbf{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbf{R}^3$ with $F(x,y,z)=(xz,0,0)$ in the positively oriented solid $S$, bounded by the paraboloid $\{x^2+y^2\}$ and the plane $\{z=1\}$"

Also, here it is the definition of the theorem i have:

**Gauss Theorem**: Let $F=(P,Q,R):U \subset \mathbf{R}^3\rightarrow{\mathbf{R}^3}$ which is $C^1$ in $U$, and $\Omega \subset U$ a Jordan measurable set such that  $S=Fr(\Omega)=\partial \Omega$ it is a *surface by pieces* and $\Omega \cup S \subset U$ then we have that:
$$\int_{\Omega}^{} \nabla \cdot \, F=\int_{S=\partial \Omega}^{}F \cdot d\sigma $$
where $\sigma$ is a parametrization.

The thing is that i think it verifies Gauss Theorem but i don't get that when i do the integrals, here is my **attempt**:

Let's define:
$$\Omega=\{(x,y,z): 0 \leq z \leq x^2+y^2 \}, z \in [0,1] $$
We want to calculate:
$$\int_{\partial \Omega }^{}F \cdot d\sigma $$
We define the following parametrization:
$\sigma_{1,2}:B\subset\mathbf{R}^2\xrightarrow{}\mathbf{R}^3$
$$\sigma_1 (u,v)=(u,v,u^2+v^2) $$
$$\sigma_2(u,v)=(u,v,0) $$
We then proceed to find the normal vectors $\frac{\partial \sigma_i}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \sigma_i}{\partial v} $

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial v}=(-2u,-2v,1) $$

Then i multiply this one for a $-1$ because i need it to point the other direction, so what i get is $(2u,2v,-1)$.
Also
$$\frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial v}=(0,0,1) $$
We do calculate $F\cdot d\sigma_1=2u^2(u^2+v^2)$ and $F\cdot d\sigma_2=0$.
We proceed to calculate the integral (which i will do it in polar coordinates):
$$ \int_{B}^{} F \cdot d\sigma_1 \cdot (\frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial v})=\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{1} 2 r^5 cos^2 \theta  dr d\theta= \frac{\pi}{3}$$
(i also did use symbolab to compute it just  to make sure i did not make an error myself).
By the other hand, we need to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{\Omega}^{} \nabla \cdot F $$
$\Omega$ is the same as before, we then proceed to calculate the integral in cylindrical coordinates, we also have that $\nabla \cdot F= z$ so
$$\int_{\Omega}^{}  \nabla \cdot F=\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{r^2} hr \, dh dr d \theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

And as i said at the beginning, i do not know what i am doing wrong, did i messed up at the parametrization? or it does not satisfies the conditions of the theorem?... any hint will be useful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note your second integral is set up incorrectly. Otherwise you working is fine.

[image]

So it should be $\, \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{r^2}^{1} \, h \, r \, dh \, dr \, d\theta$

Note the limits of $h$.

Comment: Thank you, i did not see it that way.

Comment: You are welcome!